# Showing that the sequence is nondecreasing.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

If $(x_{n})$ is a bounded sequence of real numbers, let
$$y_{k} = \inf \{x_{n} : n \geq k \}, \ z_{k} = \sup \{x_{n} : n \geq k \}.$$
I want to show that $(y_{k})$ is nondecreasing, i.e., that $y_{k} \leq y_{k+1}$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$. My first thought is to prove this by induction.

Base case: Let $i = 1$, and prove that $y_{i} \leq y_{i+1},$ i.e., that $y_{1} \leq y_{2}.$ Observe that $y_{1} = \inf \{x_{1}, x_{2}, ... \}.$ Then $y_{1}$ is a lower bound for $\{x_{1}, x_{2}, ... \},$ and if $y_{1} < \alpha$, then $\alpha$ is not a lower bound for that set. Also, $y_{2} = \inf \{x_{2}, x_{3}, ... \}.$ Then $y_{2}$ is a lower bound for $\{x_{2}, x_{3}, ... \},$ and if $y_{2} < \beta$, then $\beta$ is not a lower bound for that set.

But I'm not sure how to use this info to proceed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is false. Let $x_1=1, x_n=0, \forall n>1$, then $y_1=y_2=0<x_1$. Btw, what you did is NOT induction.

Comment: $y_k=\inf\{x_n : n \ge k \} = \min(\inf\{x_n : n \ge k+1 \}, x_k) \le \inf\{x_n : n \ge k+1\} = y_{k+1}$

Comment: yes, thanks @MathFail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $(x_n)$ is bounded, it means that there exists a number $M>0$ such that $|x_n| \leq M$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. The boundedness of the set gives us a finite infimum, as $-M$ is a lower bound for all $x_n$.

The infimum of a set is the greatest lower bound, which means that it is less than or equal to all the elements of the set and greater than or equal to all lower bounds of that set.

As an infimum $y_{k+1}$, must be less than or equal to all elements in $\{x_n: n\geq k+1\}$. As an infimum, $y_{k}$ must be less than or equal to all elements in $\{x_n : n \geq k+1\}$ in addition to being less than or equal to $x_{k}$. Thus, we see that:

$$y_k = \min(\inf\{x_n: n \geq k+1\}, x_k) \leq \inf\{x_n: n \geq k+1\} = y_{k+1}$$

To be explicit, if $x_k$ is greater than or equal to the infimum of $\{x_n: n\geq k+1\}$, then $y_k = y_{k+1}$, but if $x_k$ is less than that infimum, then $y_k < y_{k+1}$.

Comment: Since $y_k$ is a greatest lower bound, it must be less than or equal to every element in $\{x_k, x_{k+1}, x_{k+2}, \ldots\}$. Consider two cases: either $x_k < \inf\{x_n : n \geq k+1\} = y_{k+1}$ or $x_k  \geq y_{k+1}$. In the first case, $y_k$ is equal to $x_k$, which equal to the minimum of $x_k$ and $y_{k+1}$. In the second case $y_k$ is equal to $y_{k+1}$. In both cases, $y_k$ is less than or equal to all $x_n$ such that $n \geq k$.

Comment: "In the first case, $y_{k}$ is equal to $x_{k}$". But how can we know this for certain? Isn't it the case that the greatest lower bound of a set need not be in the set? Thus how can we say for certain that $y_{k} = x_{k}$? That's my confusion.

Comment: It is because in the first case we specified $x_k < \inf\{x_n:n\geq k+1\}$, so we know that it is in the set in this case (the infimum is actually a minimum in this case). I'm going through the cases in order, so the first case is when $x_k$ is less than $y_{k+1}$ and the second case is when $x_k\geq y_{k+1}$. In the second case, where $x_k \geq y_{k+1}$, you might get an infimum that is not in the set, i.e. $(x_k = 6, x_{k+1} = 0.1, x_{k+2}= 0.01, x_{k+3}=0.001, \ldots)$ as you're taking $\min(x_k, y_{k+1}) = \min(6,0)=0$, and this is less than all elements and not in the seq.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I appreciate it!